# How to truncate string from last two underscores with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to truncate the string from its last second Underscore.
e.g. If my string is GroupOwner_1_2, I want to trucate _1_2 and get only GroupOwner as result with regular expression.

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: Why do so? Go from 0 to FirstIndexOf('_')

Comment: why regex when you can `x.Substring(0, x.LastIndexOf('_', x.LastIndexOf('_') - 1))` (pseudo). Or use a simple loop for that matter

Comment: @SimpleVar, I think it should be FirstIndexOf, but for the rest I agree

Comment: @SimpleVar The problem with an implementation based on `LastIndexOf` is error checking: OP would have to check for `-1` return twice, and decide what to do. My personal rule of thumb is that when I need to match one item, `IndexOf` wins; when I need to match three items, regex wins; two items is a gray zone, depending on regex complexity.

Answer (score 1):

The first task is to describe the part that you want to match: it's an underscore, followed by zero or more non-underscores, followed by another underscore, and some more non-underscores before hitting the end of string.

The regex for it looks like this:

```
_[^_]*_[^_]*$
```

Matching it and replacing with an empty string drops the matched part from the string.

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/fN5Met)

You can further simplify your expression by "folding" the identical parts:

```
(_[^_]*){2}$
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/lL1Zxr)

Comment: If you want to optimize the regex matching, use `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` flag.

Answer (score 1):

You may use LINQ instead of a regex:

```
var str = "GroupOwner_1_2";
var result = string.Join("_", str.Split('_').Reverse().Skip(2).Reverse());
// => GroupOwner
```

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/wob5RM)

The `str.Split('_')` splits the string into chunks with `_`, `.Reverse()` reverses the items in the result, `.Skip(2)` discards the first (that are actually last) chunks and `.Reverse()` reverts the item order to the original one. The `string.Join` builds the resulting string.

Note that if you pass `GroupOwner12` or `GroupOwner_12` the result will be an empty string since there are no 2 underscores in the input.